# How to add a new domain for translations in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, translation

I'm using symfony and in my bundle I need to create some translations, but I rather do it in a different domain than "messages", like FOS User Bundle does (they use the FOSUserBundle domain).

So I created a MyBundle.en.yml file with my translations, but they are not loaded. I've read in the documentation I need to do this:

```
$translator->addLoader('xlf', new XliffFileLoader());

$translator->addResource('xlf', 'messages.fr.xlf', 'fr_FR');
$translator->addResource('xlf', 'admin.fr.xlf', 'fr_FR', 'admin');
$translator->addResource(
    'xlf',
    'navigation.fr.xlf',
    'fr_FR',
    'navigation'
);
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/translation.html#using-message-domains

But where should I do that?

**Update**

After some investigation, if I run the debug for the translations it says that all the translation I'm using for my domain in the template are missing.

My translation file is located at 
`src/Acme/Bundle/MyBundle/resources/translations/MyDomain.yml`

I tried to located in `app/Resources/translation/MyDomain.yml` but same result.

I also tried to delete the cache (`rm -rf app/cache`) but still not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Symfony will automatically do this for you if you place your files in the correct location(s). You can find a full description of the conventions assumed by Symfony in the documentation: https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html#translation-resource-file-names-and-locations

The [Best Practices-guide](https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/i18n.html#translation-source-file-location) recommends storing them in `app/Resources/translations/`. Alternatively you can put them in your bundle's translations folder: `src/MyBundle/Resources/translations`.

Please be aware that you have to specify your domain when using the translator, e.g. in your twig templates. See:

- https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/translation.html#using-message-domains
- https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html#twig-templates

Comment: I think I'm doing all that correctly, I updated the question with some more tests I did

Comment: In the path you posted in your updated question I spot 2 mistakes:

 - the directory resources is lowercase, but should start with uppercase R
 - The translation file does not specify a locale, e.g. `MyDomain.en.yml`

Comment: Yep, right! I missed the language in the file. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you have to specify the domain name. for example in twig:

```
{{ some_things | trans({}, 'my_domaine_name') }}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have something like `x.en.yaml` and you want to use it inside a twing template you can do something like this:

`{% trans from 'x' %}word_to_translate{% endtrans %}`