# Symfony3 / translation : set default domain for a bundle

Tags: symfony, yaml, translation, symfony-3.4

I'm using multiples translations files :

```
app /
  Resources /
    translations /
      messages.en.yml
      messages.fr.yml
      mailer.en.yml
      ...
src /
  AdminBundle /
    Resources /
      translations /
        admin_messages.en.yml
        ...
  PortalBundle /
    Resources /
      translations /
        portal_messages.en.yml
        ...
```

The translation works when (or):

- `admin_messages.en.yml` is renamed `messages.en.yml`
- I set the default domain in my twig files `{% trans_default_domain "admin_messages" %}`

Badly, I can't use the filename `messages.en.yml` many times and setting the default domain should not be the cleaner way

So, I'd like to override the default domain of translation from **messages** to **admin_messages** on my **admin bundle**.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your case fits in [How to add a new domain for translations in Symfony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42861590/how-to-add-a-new-domain-for-translations-in-symfony?rq=1).

As a summary, and as stated in https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html#translation-resource-file-names-and-locations, you can set the default domain in a template by using `{% trans_default_domain 'app' %}`

Comment: From Review: Hi, while links are great way of sharing knowledge, they won't really answer the question if they get broken in the future. Add to your answer the essential content of the link which answers the question. In case the content is too complex or too big to fit here, describe the general idea of the proposed solution. Remember to always keep a link reference to the original solution's website. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)